# I can't get JS working on Safari on MacOS

Tags: javascript, windows, macos

This code works on Windows, on Firefox & Chrome, but doesn't work on Mac. What's the issue? I have JavaScript enabled on the Safari settings on the MacBook.

```
<script> 
    $(function(){
        $("#includedContent").load("templates/tournaments.html");
        $("#currentEvent").load("templates/current_event.html");
    });
</script>

<div id="includedContent"></div>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors reported anywhere?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load .../templates/tournaments.html due to access control checks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a CORS issue. If you are using the scheme `file://` you will not be able to load your static templates over http.

I think this post will be helpful ["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)